# Why do the bottoms of my cookies look like cakes?

Tags: cookies

[image]

[image]

What could possibly have gone wrong? I used only 1 egg yolk with no baking soda and Melted butter:

[image]

And this is what I got after beating sugar+melted butter+yolk:

[image]

After adding dry ingredients:

[image]

And here's what it looks like in the oven:

[image]

In which step do you think I could have done something wrong? I have no idea really.

Comment: Those look fine to me. Is there some other kind of cookie you were trying to make? (Were you following a recipe? I am surprised you didn't use any baking soda and seem to have done all right.)

Comment: I'd eat those. Toss 'em my way if you don't want them, in the spirit of not wasting food and stuff...

Comment: i want it to be thin and chewy.However, it may look alright but it's too soft and easy to break in half if lifted.

Comment: Your blending mixture is inadequate, so that it allows the oil and butter to migrate downwards.

Comment: Chewy cookies also break when hot. You want to let them cool down before removing them from the sheet. And yes, they look normal to me too, not cakelike. Can you find an example of the cookie you are trying to achieve and point us there, so we know if "chewy cookie" is really what you want, or if your expectations are wrong?

Comment: @rumtscho something like this http://cannella-vita.blogspot.com/2012/07/watersheds-chocolate-chip-cookies.html

Comment: I would imagine that the bottoms of the cookies you linked to probably look a lot like yours.

Answer (score 1):

These cookies look all right, there is no need to change anything in your technique to correct the looks.

If there is a problem with the texture, then this is a different question (which, as far as I can remember, we already helped you with in another thread). But the only viable answer to this question as stated is: no need to change anything here.